# Spring MVC: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/searchCompanyDetails")
public String searchCompanyDetails(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("company") CompanyDetails company, HttpServletRequest request){
    model.put("companyName", company.getCompanyName());
    model.put("contact", new ContactInformationDTO());
    List <category> categoryList = services.getCategryList();
    model.put("categorylist", categoryList);
    model.put("comcat", new CategoryCompanyDTO());
    return "addCategory2";
}
```

MyJSP:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelattribute="contact" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addContactInfo">
    <td><form:input path="firstName" type="text"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="lastName" type="text"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="designation" type="text"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="personalNumber" type="number"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="personalEmailId" type="text"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="contactWorkLocation" type="text"/></td>
    <%-- <form:input path="companyName" type="hidden" value="${companyName}"/> --%>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
</form:form>
```

DTO Class:

```
public class ContactInformationDTO {

    private int contactId;
    private String companyName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String designation;
    private int personalNumber;
    private String personalEmailId;
    private String contactWorkLocation;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ConceptEdgeDetails] in context
>   with path [/ConceptEdge] threw exception [An exception occurred
>   processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/addCategory2.jsp at line 55
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute

Please help me where I am doing wrong?
This solution I found in here:

```
@Valid @ModelAttribute("") Class object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("id") String id
```

But not understanding is it right? or how to use it?

Comment: I think this is the right way, but not understanding why the error? So was doubting on what I am doing, I am new to spring and hibernate.

Comment: Your controller is mapped to `/searchCompanyDetails` not `/addContactInfo` which you posted in question.

Comment: I kept one controller, these are all mapped to one controller. /searchCompanyDetails and /addContactInfo mapped to methods in that controller.

Comment: Is `/addContactInfo` also mapped to method `searchCompanyDetails` ?

Comment: No, they are separate.
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/searchCompanyDetails")
 public String searchCompanyDetails(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("company") CompanyDetails company, HttpServletRequest request){}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/addContactInfo")
 public String addContactInfo(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("contact") ContactInformationDTO contactInfo, HttpServletRequest request){}
Separate methods and respective mapping in one controller.